# Is "type" a keyword in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I just came across somebody using "type" in [a piece of ES6 code](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-utils-todomvc/js/flux-infra/TodoActions.js).

```
export type Action =
  {
    type: 'todo/complete',
    id: string,
  } |
  {
    type: 'todo/create',
    text: string,
  } |
  {
    type: 'todo/destroy',
    id: string,
  } |
  {
    type: 'todo/destroy-completed',
  } |
  {
    type: 'todo/toggle-complete-all',
  } |
  {
    type: 'todo/undo-complete',
    id: string,
  } |
  {
    type: 'todo/update-text',
    id: string,
    text: string,
  };
```

Couldn't find anything that sheds light on it. Is it a keyword? What does it exactly do?

Comment: I believe this is a [Flow](http://flowtype.org/) type definition

Comment: It's not a keyword: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-keywords

Comment: @PitaJ: Make it an answer.

Comment: @PitaJ Couldn't find Flow in package.json though? Am I missing something?
https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-utils-todomvc/package.json

Comment: @aarjithn: Flow is not a node module, it's a separate binary.

Comment: @FelixKling Ah, right. It does exist in npm too though, as a wrapper. https://www.npmjs.com/package/flow-bin.

Comment: Its is NOT. I frequently use 'type' in my APIs (in JavaScript).

Comment: This is definitely no ES6 code.

Comment: If you use it as an object property name, just do this [type] to make it work. 

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As mentioned by [PitaJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33446498/is-type-a-keyword-in-javascript#comment54681282_33446498), the `type` symbol here is not part of ES6 or any earlier version of JavaScript, but rather part of the [Flow static type checker](https://flowtype.org).

[Here are the docs for the `type` symbol](https://flowtype.org/docs/type-aliases.html).

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, the [ES6 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-keywords) does not list it as a reserved keyword.

> The following tokens are ECMAScript keywords and may not be used as Identifiers in ECMAScript programs.
>
> break do  in  typeof case else    instanceof  var catch   export  new void class  extends return  while const finally super   with continue   for switch  yield debugger  function    this     default    if  throw   delete  import  try

Answer (score 2):

You can disable it

```
export interface Body {
   a: string
   b: string
   c: string
   // tslint:disable-next-line:no-reserved-keywords
   type: string
   f: string
   e: string
}
```